# 2011 MacBook Pro running 10.8.5; need incremental back up program

Tags: macbook-pro

I need to back up my Pro Tools folder to an external HDD everyday, but need a program that looks for changes and saves them only, similar to the way time machine works. Is this “appended” or “incremental” and does your Mac Guru software perform this function?